# Which JavaScript file is the angular.module() function defined in?

Tags: angularjs

I was wondering if anybody knows which file the `angular.module()` function is defined in. I ask because when I type "angular." My IDE's auto-complete feature does not show the module method on the angular object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the files in which the `.module()` is defined:

- in the build version it is the main angular.js file (corresponding to the `ngModule`): http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.2/angular.js, check the line 1052
- in the source code it is here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/loader.js#L67

You might want to search for the `function module(name, requires, configFn)` string to locate it in your version of AngularJS.

Comment: Yes, I see it.  But why won't my IDE don't see it as a method on the angular variable?  I would like to type "angular." and see all the variables and methods on it.  In this case, I would like to see angular.module as an option but I don't. I only see angular.element instead.

Comment: Don't know which IDE you are using but I'm happy with WebStorm. Right + click on a module will take you to a comment for a module so it is not bad. Plus WebStorm has this rather cool plugin for AngularJS.

Comment: I see.  I am using Eclipse right not but plan to check out WebStorm.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to the AngularJS documentation it's in the [ng module](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.module).